# text() to display a greek letter with subscript in R plot

Tags: r, plot

I was wondering how I could make the letter "**sigma**" appear in Greek **with the subscript** "***m***" in the **text()** part of the **R code below?:**

```
curve(dnorm(x,175.3,.961),160,190,type="l")

sigmam <- dnorm(177.4,175.3,.961)/ dnorm(177.4,176,4)

text(165,.285,paste("sigmam", "=", round(1/sigmam,digits=2)))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out `?plotmath` for relevant examples of how to piece this sort of thing together. For instance, here's one adapted from the "*## How to combine "math" and numeric variables :*"

```
curve(dnorm(x,175.3,.961),160,190,type="l")
sigmam <- dnorm(177.4,175.3,.961)/ dnorm(177.4,176,4)

text(165,.285, bquote(Sigma[m] == .(round(sigmam,2))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, and I guess I can bold or italicize the greek letters?

Comment: @parvinkarimi - actually, I don't think you can - from `?plotmath` - "*Note that bold, italic and bolditalic do not apply to symbols, and hence not to the Greek symbols such as mu which are displayed in the symbol font. They also do not apply to numeric constants.*"